# Find line breaks from MATLAB system command

Tags: string, matlab, system, printf

I'm trying to parse the result string from a system command to an external program.

```
[status,result] = system(cmd);
```

result prints out on my console with its lines correctly broken out, i.e.

line1

line2

...

But it's actually just a single long character array, and there are no newline characters anywhere.  How does matlab know when to print out a new line?  And how can I separate the char array into its separate lines for further parsing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on operation system different characters represent end of line. It can be `\n`, `\r`, `\f` or their combination. Those characters have ASCII code less then 30. So you can look for them with, for example, `find(results < 30)` to display their position in the string , and `int32(results(results < 30))` to see their code.

```
int32(sprintf('\n\r\f'))

ans =

      10          13          12
```

Then you can use the code you get to split the string:

```
regexp(results, char(13), 'split')
```

---

If you are not interested on which characters are used as end-of-line, you can just try:

```
regexp(results, '[\f\n\r]', 'split')
```

Answer (score 2):

Further to Andrey's answer, you can split the string into a cell array using the following command:

```
split_result = regexp(result, '\n', 'split');
```

This uses regular expressions to split the string at each newline character.

You can then access each line of the system command output using:

```
 split_result{index}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using the `\n` character.
Consider this use case:

```
x = sprintf('12123\nxyz');
disp(x);
```

The result is:

> 12123
>   xyz

So you can just find everywhere that the special `\n` character is.

```
indexes = strfind(x,sprintf('\n'));
```

Check out this site : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/

Comment: The problem is precisely that -- there are no \n characters in the result string.  So I can't parse it that way.  Everywhere Matlab knows to go to the next line, there do not appear to be any special characters.

Answer (score 1):

As of Matlab R2016b you may also use the command `splitlines()` which will automatically handle the newline definitions for you.